# En chart.js imprimir grafica en un csv o Excel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, chart.js

Hola compañeros estoy intentando imprimir mi grafica en un excel (xlsx o csv) el problema es que solo he encontrado que solo se imprimen los datos de la tabla mas no la grafica como tal. Entonces quisiera saber si existe alguna manera o tengo que utilizar otro tipo de plugin para que pueda realizar esto, por ahora todo lo que quiero imprimir es esto:

```js
<script>
 var cadena = "";
 var datos = "";
 var respuestas = "";
 var datosSeparados = "";
 var downloadBtn = document.getElementById('downloadBtn');
 var canvas = document.getElementById("Graf01");
 var frecuencias = [];
 $(document).ready(function(){
  @foreach($preguntas as $p)
  var respuestas{{$p->id_pesp}} = [];
  @if($p->tipo != "1" && $p->tipo != "2")
  if($("#graf{{$p->id_pesp}}")){
   cadena = ""
   @foreach($resultados as $res)
    @if($res->id_pesp == $p->id_pesp)
    cadena += "{{$res->respuesta}};";
    @endif
   @endforeach
   datos = cadena.substring(0, cadena.length - 1);
   alert(datos);
   datosSeparados = datos.split(';');
   @foreach($respuestas as $r)
   var f = 0;
   @if($r->id_pesp == $p->id_pesp)
    respuestas{{$p->id_pesp}}.push("{{$r->respuestas}}");
    for(var i = 0; i < datosSeparados.length; i++){
     if(datosSeparados[i]=={{$r->id_res}}){
      f++;
     }
    }
    frecuencias.push(f);
   @endif
   @endforeach
   var grafica = $('#graf{{$p->id_pesp}}');

   var grafica = new Chart(canvas, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
           labels: respuestas{{$p->id_pesp}},
           datasets: [{
               label: 'Encuesta Especifica',
               data: frecuencias,
               lineTension: 0,
                backgroundColor: [
                   'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                   'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                   'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                   'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                   'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                   'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
               ],
               borderColor: [
                   'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                   'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                   'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                   'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                   'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                   'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
               ],
               borderWidth: 1
           }]
       }
   });
  }
  @endif
  @endforeach
```

Consegui que lo hiciera en PDF pero falta la parte de Excel, gracias por su ayuda,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo ayudandote de la librería [Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) en su versión 2.1

La lógica seria crear el excel, pasar los datos al mismo y luego seleccionar esos datos y crear los gráficos correspondientes.

Te dejo un ejemplo a para que puedas guiarte, esta podria ser una funcion en un controlador a la que llamar para que se cree el excel:

```
public function export(Request $request)
{
    //nombre del archivo
    $name = date("Y-m-d H-i-s");

    //de alguna manera obetenes los datos, supongamos tenemos una Collection de items como la siguiente
    $datosDelGrafico = [
        {
            "nombre": "Reloj",
            "total": 50
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Cartera",
            "total": 25
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Bolse",
            "total": 75
        },
    ]

    $excel = Excel::create($name, function($excel) use (datosDelGrafico) {

        $excel->sheet('Worksheet', function($sheet) use (datosDelGrafico) {

            $datos = array(
                array("Producto", "Cantidad")
            );

            foreach ($datosDelGrafico as $producto){
                $data= array($producto->nombre, $producto->total);
                array_push($datos, $data);
            }

            //agregamos los datos al excel
            $sheet->fromArray($datos, null, 'A1', false, false);


            //seleccionamos el campo que tiene la leyenda, "Cantidad" en la celda B1
            $dataSeriesLabels = array(
                new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$B$1', NULL, 1),
            );

            //seleccionamos las categorias en este caso reloj, cartera, etc que que para este ejemplo se encuentran en A2 hasta A4
            $xAxisTickValues = array(
                new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$4', NULL, 10),
            );

            //seleccionamos los valores totales que para este ejemplo se encuentran en B2 hasta B4
            $dataSeriesValues = array(
                new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$B$2:$B$4', NULL, 10),
            );


            //todo lo que sigue crea el chart en base a lo que seleccionamos anteriormente
            $layout = new \PHPExcel_Chart_Layout();
            $layout->setShowVal(TRUE);

            $ChartGroupType = NULL;
            $yAxis = NULL;

            $chartType = \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART;
            $layout->setShowPercent(TRUE);

            $ChartGroupType = \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD;

            $yAxis = new \PHPExcel_Chart_Axis();
            $yAxis->setAxisOptionsProperties(
                \PHPExcel_Chart_Axis::AXIS_LABELS_NEXT_TO,
                null,
                null,
                \PHPExcel_Properties::ORIENTATION_REVERSED
            );

            $series = new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
                $chartType,                                 //          plotType
                $ChartGroupType,                            //          tipo de agrupamiento
                range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1),       //          plotOrder
                $dataSeriesLabels,                          //          plotLabel
                $xAxisTickValues,                           //          plotCategory
                $dataSeriesValues                           //          plotValues
            );

            $series->setPlotDirection(\PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_VERTICAL);

            $plotArea = new \PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea($layout, array($series));
            $legend = new \PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(\PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL, false);
            $title = new \PHPExcel_Chart_Title("titulo del chart");

            $chart = new \PHPExcel_Chart(
                "nombredechart",    //          name
                $title,             //          title
                $legend,            //          legend
                $plotArea,          //          plotArea
                true,               //          plotVisibleOnly
                0,                  //          displayBlanksAs
                null,               //          xAxisLabel
                null,               //          yAxisLabel
                NULL,               //          xAxis
                $yAxis              //          yAxis
            );

            //seteamos en que posicion queremos que se vea el chart
            $chart->setTopLeftPosition('D1');
            $chart->setBottomRightPosition('J10');ç

            //lo agregamos al excel.
            $sheet->addChart($chart);
        });
    });

    //le podemos setear alguna info
    $excel->setTitle('Un titulo');
    $excel->setCreator('tu nombre');
    $excel->setCompany('tu empresa');
    $excel->setDescription('Datos exportados de seccion Cultura');


    //a partir de aca hacemos lo que nos parezca, por ejemplo lo guardamos
    $excel->store('xlsx', storage_path('app/public/excel'), true);

    //o iniciamos la descarga
    $excel->download('xlsx');
}
```

Espero que sea de ayuda, saludos!